# The parsing of the ruleset failed when executing rules on Bluemix

Tags: ibm-cloud, business-rules

When testing a ruleset deployed on the Business Rules service on Bluemix, I see the following error:

> An error occurred while the rule session was created:
>   com.ibm.rules.res.xu.internal.XUException: The parsing of the ruleset
>   /myRuleApp/2.0/myRuleset/1.0 failed Problem occurred loading
>   translation : foo.Bar : Cannot find execution class "foo.Bar" for
>   translating business class "foo.Bar" .

EDIT:

Other similar symptoms I've found are:

> Error when translating parameter  "myParam":  Cannot translate class 
>   "test.MyClass"
>
> Error when translating parameter "myParam": Cannot translate class
>   "test.MyClass"
>
> Error when translating package "myRulePackage": Cannot translate class
>   "test.MyClass".
>
> Unresolved resources or libraries: [resuri://XOM.zip/1.0]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error occurred because I had not deployed the XOM with the definition for the class foo.Bar with the RuleApp.
To resolve this error, I deployed the XOM from the Rule Designer plug-in, by right-clicking the rule project name, and then selecting Rule Execution Server > Deploy XOM from the menu. I made sure through the RES console to point from the ruleset to the Managed XOM resource that was needed for parsing.

EDIT:

In general, for this and related errors:

-- Deploy/redeploy all XOM classes to Rule Execution Server. After redeploying, in the Rule Execution Server console, check that the ruleset points to the latest version of the XOM deployed.

-- In the case of an "Unresolved resources or libraries" error, correct the path  to the existing resources for the ruleset, through the Rule Execution Server console.

-- Ensure that the XOM and its dependencies were compiled for a Java version that is compatible with the [JVM running the server that hosts Rule Execution Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33657349/how-do-i-find-which-java-version-is-being-used-to-execute-my-rules-on-bluemix). For example, classes that are compiled to comply with a Java 7 target would not work on a Java 6 JVM.