# How do I find which Java version is being used to execute my rules on Bluemix?

Tags: ibm-cloud, business-rules

I am executing my rules on the Business Rules service on Bluemix, and want to know which Java runtime version is used. How do I find this information?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This information is available if I enable tracing for the payload, for example by invoking it using https://brsv2-instanceID.domain/DecisionService/run.jsp?path=/ruleApp/1.0/ruleset/1.0&trace=true

(for example: https://brsv2-12345678.ng.bluemix.net/DecisionService/run.jsp?path=/myRuleApp/1.0/myRules/1.0&trace=true)

I made sure that infoSystemProperties was set to true for JSON.

The trace after execution of the request contains a "systemProperties" element/entry, which includes the Java information.

The answer [How can I trace rules in the Business Rules service on Bluemix?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29639786/how-can-i-trace-rules-in-the-business-rules-service-on-bluemix/29639854#29639854) has more information on tracing.